# cannot resolve symbol R and Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android

So these two problems appeared yesterday when I was working on adding two new activities for my app. In my main activity class the R symbol cannot be resolved although it was normally resolved before. Here is [My Android project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv897.png)

I have been using the picture to text converter application from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc_Zmkf16kM&t=1s). That application contains cropper, quick-start, sample and tess-two modules. The only one I have changed is sample.
The new .xml files that I added I have removed in hope of the errors resolving themselves, but it hasn't helped.
The following part of the code is the part of my main in which the error occures along with the imports.

```
package com.vish.imagetotext.ocr.sample;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.system.ErrnoException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.example.croppersample.*;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;


import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by VisH on 19-06-2016.
 * Edited by antun 20-05-2017.
 */
public class main  extends Activity {

    private CropImageView mCropImageView;
    Bitmap converted;
    EditText textView;
    private TessOCR mTessOCR;
    private Uri mCropImageUri;
    public static final String lang = "eng";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DemoOCR/";
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Button btnInstructions;
    private Button btnCredits;
    private Button btnSendCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_main);
        textView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        mCropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };
```

When I try to run the app, Clean Build or Rebuild, these errors occur and the values-v24.xml opens:

> GPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/antun/Downloads/Demo
>   Image to
>   Text/sample/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/antun/Downloads/Demo
>   Image to
>   Text/sample/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml","position":{"startLine":3}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>   Text/sample/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>   Text/sample/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':sample:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media"/>
</resources>
```

Here is my a_main.xml file aswell:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_atop"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="onLoadImageClick"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Učitaj sliku"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:onClick="onCropImageClick"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Izreži sliku"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="Pošalji kod"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView


        android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:minHeight="200dp" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnInstructions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="Upute"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCredits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="O aplikaciji"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: running with --stacktrace the following errors came up:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/antun/Downloads/Demo
>   Image to
>   Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/antun/Downloads/Demo
>   Image to
>   Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml","position":{"startLine":3}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>   /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>   Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>   Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':quick-start:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':quick-start:processDebugResources'.  at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>     aapt  at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:185)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
>     ... 78 more Caused by:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>     aapt  at
>     com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:873)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:178)
>     ... 85 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>     '/home/antun/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt' with arguments
>     {package -f --no-crunch -I
>     /home/antun/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M
>     /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>     Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>     -S /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug -m -J
>     /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>     Text/quick-start/build/generated/source/r/debug -F
>     /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>     Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_
>     --debug-mode --custom-package com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.quick.start -0 apk
>     --output-text-symbols /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
>     --no-version-vectors}     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
>     at
>     com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
>     at
>     com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:871)
>     ... 86 more Caused by:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>     '/home/antun/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt' with arguments
>     {package -f --no-crunch -I
>     /home/antun/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M
>     /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>     Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>     -S /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug -m -J
>     /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>     Text/quick-start/build/generated/source/r/debug -F
>     /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to
>     Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_
>     --debug-mode --custom-package com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.quick.start -0 apk
>     --output-text-symbols /home/antun/Downloads/Demo Image to Text/quick-start/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
>     --no-version-vectors}     at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:75)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
>     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
>     at
>     com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
>     at
>     com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>     at
>     com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>     at
>     com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
>     at
>     com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>     '/home/antun/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with
>     non-zero exit value 1     at
>     org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
>     ... 9 more
>
> BUILD FAILED

Comment: Do you recall what you changed recently to arrive at this error?  This is one reason why you should be versioning your work.  If you were using Git, you could rollback to before you had this error, then take baby steps to find out where things start going wrong.

Comment: I have only added two new xml files and I don't know where it went wrong. I didn't use git because the tess-two folder has 1.6gb so I didn't whether it's smart to push such projects to git.

Comment: So are you saying that removing those two XML files doesn't fix the problem?

Comment: It didn't remove neither of the problems

Comment: This would be a good time for you to start using version control.  Again, if you were using a VC tool, you could easily rollback to yesterday when this problem did not exist.  Most likely, your issue is just a small thing, but it may be hard to diagnose it.

Comment: I will learn how to do that, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Update your build.gradle `buildToolsVersion` and  `dependencies` with these version

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```